Function adapting to mutable or non-mutable input
I wanted to build a function/method that could adapt if a non-mutable or mutable reference was provided.
I tried something like this (playground):
trait TryAsMut<'a, T> where T: 'a {
    fn try_as_mut(self) -> Result<&'a mut T,&'a T>;
}

impl<'a, T> TryAsMut<'a, T> for &'a T {
    fn try_as_mut(self) -> Result<&'a mut T,&'a T> {Err(self)}
}
impl<'a, T> TryAsMut<'a, T> for &'a mut T {
    fn try_as_mut(self) -> Result<&'a mut T,&'a T> {Ok(self)}
}

fn option_inc<'a>(value: impl TryAsMut<'a, usize>) -> Option<usize> {
    match value.try_as_mut() {
        Ok(u)  => { *u += 1; None },
        Err(u) => { Some(*u + 1) },
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut u = 5;

    println!("u + 1 = {}", option_inc(&u).unwrap());
    option_inc(&mut u);
    println!("u = {u}");
}

resulting in:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.58s
     Running `target/debug/playground`

Standard Output

u + 1 = 6
u = 6

It works, but is there an idiomatic way of doing it?

The idiomatic way is to have two separate functions. But this question isn't really suited here.

I don't think there is something idiomatic for this (and your solution looks really nice). Possibly things will get more simple when generic keywords come in: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-generic-keywords/18412

Your code is as good as it gets, provided you really need to dispatch on mutability. If I were you, I'd probably reconsider the requirement, not the solution.
